# LWC header for subquery

Tags: class, salesforce, apex, soql, lwc

I have a problem when I used the SOQL sub query header in LWC. Initially, I wanted to show the UnitPrice from the PricebookEntries using the Product2 as base query (from). But I got a problem initializing the header in LWC.

Class:

```
public static List<Product2> fetchProducts(){
        
        PriceBook2 pb2Standard =[select Id from Pricebook2 where isStandard=true limit 1];
        system.debug('Pricebook ID >> ' + pb2Standard.Id);
        return [select Id, Name,
                ,(select Product2Id, UnitPrice from PricebookEntries where Pricebook2Id = :pb2Standard.Id), Family
               from Product2
               where Id in (select Product2Id from PricebookEntry where Pricebook2Id =:pb2Standard.Id )
               and IsActive = true and Item_Status_Name__c NOT IN ('Unclassified')];
    }
```

LWC:

```
headers = {
        
        Name:"Product Name",
        PricebookEntries.UnitPrice:"UnitPrice",
        Id:"ProductID"
    }
```

May I ask for your help on showing the UnitPrice from PricebookEntries.
I already tried:

```
PricebookEntries__r.UnitPrice:"UnitPrice"
PricebookEntries__r[0].UnitPrice:"UnitPrice"
"PricebookEntries.UnitPrice":"UnitPrice"
[PricebookEntries.UnitPrice]:"UnitPrice"
PricebookEntries(UnitPrice):"UnitPrice"
```

Thank you in advance!

TO show the UnitPrice from the LWC header initialization.